# How do I play a stream from a RTMP server to a HTML5?

Tags: html5-video, video.js, rtmp

How do I play a stream from a RTMP server to a HTML5? Tried using the videojs-flash plugin to run the RMTP server. Shows the error:-

Cross-origin plugin content from https://vjs.zencdn.net/swf/5.4.1/video-js.swf must have a visible size larger than 400 x 300 pixels, or it will be blocked. Invisible content is always blocked.

Comment: i removed the error by setting width and height of the video......but the video does not play yet....